# MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE crash for some devices

Tags: java, android, camera, onactivityresult

I open camera with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in my app. Some devices crash. It doesn't even get into the onActivityResult() method. Constantly crashing on onCreate() . As I mentioned, it happens on some devices. Redmi Note 10 and Samsung Galaxy Tab A are the devices I get the error. I did not encounter any errors on other Android 11 devices.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getImage();
    }
 

private void getImage(){
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File output = new File(dir, "photo.jpg");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
              Uri  contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), ActivityManager.GetInstance().getCurrentActivity().getApplication().getPackageName()+".provider", output);
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, contentUri);
            } else {
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));
            }
            if(i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null && contentUri != null)
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        }
}
```

Comment: did you call `setContentView`?

Comment: and I will prefer not to use `startActivityForResult`. It is deprecated. Use `activityResultLauncher` instead

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal yes

Comment: can you share the exception code?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal Logcat  error does not fall, this is actually the situation that forces me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Seems that the crash happens when you tap the button to take the photo. Anyway, after trying many things, the only one that "fix" the issue was to updating/rebooting the device. I don't know if only the reboot would work, or if the update is needed, but everything else didn't help me. If anyone could correct it, or maybe have better information about it, please share.